# how to give multiple values to a select-option tag?

Tags: php, html

Here,i am trying to get multiple values from one select tag, as a user selecting an option then one value we should give but in case of two or multiple values how we can deal with it?

```
<?php
include 'database.php';      
$queryy = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT d.driver_name,mob_no,d.vehicle_no
from driver_info d JOIN login l ON l.seller_id=d.seller_id where d.status='free' and l.seller_id=".$login_session);

echo '<select name="driver_name">';
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($queryy)) 
{
echo '<option value="'.$row['driver_name'].'" value="'.$row['mob_no'].'">'.$row['driver_name'].'</option>';
echo '<br>';
}
?>
```

Comment: Why you need this kind of multiple values?? You can use a single value and concatenate two value into it.

Comment: @ Frayne Konok i need values 'driver_name' and 'mob_no' on one option

Comment: you can use a separator in the value attribute for two real values, or you can use two different select tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this possible with JS help, with write Events for selected option and sent list arguments for example. HTML don't understand TWICE value in the one element.

Another way it's for example in the value do something like this

```
echo '<option value="'.$row['driver_name'].'_'.$row['mob_no'].'">'.$row['driver_name'].'</option>';
```

And on the server parse result for example:

```
$two_values = explode('_', $_POST['driver_name']);
//$two_values will be Array with 2 items
```

Comment: but how can i sepearate 'driver_name' and 'mob_no'... as i want to use 'mob_no' independent?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<!-- here name is of array type, so that it can hold multiple values in it -->
<select name="my_select[]">
...
</select>

$selectedOptions = $_REQUEST['my_select'];    
// It contains the user selection in an array
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have two `value` property inside the `option` tag. You can concatenate the value you need in this way:

```
value="'.$row['driver_name'].'_'.$row['mob_no'].'"
```

and in server side you can explode that post value.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is pass the name of the select as an array

```
"driver_name[]"
```

Then fetch the value of the array in your script:

```
$driver_name= $_POST['driver_name'];    
<?php
    include 'database.php';      
    $queryy = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT d.driver_name,mob_no,d.vehicle_no
    FROM driver_info d JOIN login l ON l.seller_id=d.seller_id WHERE d.status='free' and l.seller_id=".$login_session);

    echo '<select name="driver_name[]">';
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($queryy)) 
    {
    echo '<option value="'.$row['driver_name'].'" value="'.$row['mob_no'].'">'.$row['driver_name'].'</option>';
    echo '<br>';
    }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather do this and on return of the value explode.

```
echo '<option value="'.$row['driver_name'].'-'.$row['mob_no'].'">'.$row['driver_name'].'</option>';
```